# How can I tell if I have IIS Express or Full version installed?

Tags: iis, iis-express

I have two machines: Windows 10 Pro, and Windows 10 Home. I have enabled IIS on both of them. From both machines, going to IIS -> File -> About shows this dialog:

[image]

One might assume that I'm dealing with the full version of IIS simply due to the lack of the word "Express".

Is there any simple way to confirm if a machine has full or express installed?

Comment: IIS Express is part of Visual Studio. The fact that you have IIS manager installed means that you have full IIS. Also you can go to Control Panel -> Uninstall Programs -> Add Features and check there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You opened IIS Manager to see such a dialog and IIS Manager is only part of full IIS, while IIS is part of Windows.

If you want to check that in code, then there are other ways such as checking Windows CBS data, or reading registry key.

IIS Express is completely another software, which is an MSI package to be installed either with Visual Studio or individually. To test its installation, you either check the Programs dialogue as the comment said, or query MSI data or registry keys.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just out of curiosity: If everyone who has Windows is getting it for free, why would anyone need to pay for it?

Comment: @BCA define "it" please, or I am confused at what you are referring to.

Comment: I am sure that there is a paid, full version of IIS. I just wonder anyone would need to pay for it. In fact that's what led me to post this question, since I thought, in light of there being a paid version, full version, why would I have it on my system?

Comment: @BCA that can worth a long blog post. Here full IIS is used to distinguish from IIS Express, but the true "full featured IIS" is only available on Windows Server editions which are priced very high. Desktops such as Windows 10 does ship with IIS, but certain features are missing. The feature availability matrix is very complicated.

Answer (score 4):

IIS Express is normally installed into your 32-bit Program Files folder.  So, to see if it's there you can try:

```
C:\>cd "\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express"
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express>iisexpress /?
```

Full IIS is normally installed as a service called "World Wide Web Publishing Service" or "w3svc" for short.  So, to see if it's there you can try:

```
C:\>net start w3svc
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you have IIS manager installed, you have *full* IIS.**

IIS Express is part of Visual Studio and appears in the Windows system tray when you run a web application/web site from within Visual Studio.