# IIS, IIS Express and IIS Manager in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express

I am using Visual Studio 2017 in Windows 10 and the facts are:

- `IIS Express 10.0` is installed (I can see that in `Programs and Features`).
- When I start the application (Ctrl-F5) the browser is launched and sends an Http request to e.g. `localhost:65456` which is an instance of IIS Express (I can tell that from the icon in the system tray)
- I am running `IIS Manager 10.0` and the Default Web Site points to `localhost` which when being written as URL to a browser it responds with an `IIS` HTML page

So, *I am very confused*. I cannot see `IIS` anywhere installed in my machine. However, `IIS Manager` refers to what? To `IIS or to IIS Express`? If localhost is an `IIS instance` how `localhost:65456` is an `IIS Express instance`?

Comment: a quick search  > [Asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36773110/how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-iis-express-or-full-version-installed). Normally you can turn on IIS as windows feature and you should have the full version.

Comment: IIS is a Windows component, so it is in Control Panel | Programs | enable Windows Features. IIS Manager can only manage IIS. Why cannot `localhost:65456` be IIS Express (or another web server)? Once you learn computer network well enough, the answer is crystal clear.